# Travis-ci testing node/Vue app , got cross-env: not found

Tags: node.js, vue.js, travis-ci

aiming at using Travis-ci for continuous integration , I am processing in my settings...  however I get stuck now with this error upon executing package.json scrip test

```
cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run --browsers ChromeHeadless

sh: 1: cross-env: not found
```

however, the cross-env package is installed in the dv dependencies

```
"cross-env": "^5.0.5",
```

here is the log : [Travis build log](https://travis-ci.org/erwin16/Pomodoro/builds/287559759)

Answer (score 0):

Error in travis.yml

should be

```
install:
  - yarn
```

script:
      - yarn test

and not

```
install:
  - yarn test
```

!! my mistake